# Использование не PoD типов данных в shared memory c++

Tags: c++, процесс, ipc

**Как изменять не PoD поля в случае использования shared memory?** Я так понимаю, что для PoD типов подобный подход "в лоб" работает и на выделенной в mmap памяти поле класса изменяется. Однако поле типа string в данном случае останется неизменным. Каким образом его можно изменить? 
P.s. Вопрос чисто учебный, так что если вы подведете под ответ некоторую теоретическую базу - будет здорово.

UPD: не PoD поле остается неизменным в parent-процессе. В child-процессе оно-таки меняется, но это порождает еще больше вопросов :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

 class human
 {
 public:
   string name;
   int age;
   human()
   {
   name = '\0';
   age = 0;
   }
   ~human() {}
 void set()
   {
     cout << "Enter name" << endl;
     cin >> name;
     cout << "Enter age" << endl;
     cin >> age;
   }
   void print()
   {
     cout << name << "   " << age << endl;
   }
 };

 main(int argc, char * argv[])
 {
    pid_t cpid;
    char buf;
    human* shared;
    human non;
    shared = (human*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(*shared), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    *shared  = non;
    cpid = fork(); // duplicate the current process
    if (cpid == 0) // if I am the child then
     {
      shared->set();
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else // if I am the parent then
    {
      wait(NULL); // wait for the child process to exit before I do the same
      cout << "Human:" << endl;
      shared->print();
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
      return 0;
 }
```

Comment: все работает. добавь дебаг-вывода немножко в иф: `HumanChild:
Enter name
qqt
Enter age
123
Human:
   123`. Для компилятора пофиг pod или не pod, в данном случае. Плюс за то, что разбираешься сидишь. Олсо не кастуй в сишном стиле - я про `(human*)`

Comment: @strangeqargo Я вас не до конца понял, но все-таки. Попробовал сделать вывод в child-процессе, как вы и сказали - все работает. Но тогда возникает вопрос: почему вывод в parent-процессе выводит только измененное поле int?

Comment: @strangeqargo Про каст спасибо за совет. Поделитесь как это делается в с++?

Comment: http://cppblogs.blogspot.ru/2013/08/c-style-casts.html, а про name да, ты прав. кстати, делаешь sizeof объекта, который может изменить размер уже во время выполнения.  ждем гуру, ну или сами допетрим. если иницализировать "строкой", а не 'char', сегфолтит

Comment: @strangeqargo а где строкой инициализировали? Я попробовал в конструкторе инициализировать строкой "Who i am?", в parent он выдает 'Who i ' в качестве значения поля name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя так делать. Сериализуйте данные в разделяемую память, а потом десериализуйте на выходе.

`std::string` может содержать указатель на внешнюю память, поэтому то, что Вы выделили память под сам объект строки в общей памяти ничего не значит — данные лежат совсем в другом месте.

Конечно, может так совпасть, что оставив код неизменным и изменив строку в одном процессе, это изменение будет видно и в другом, но это частный случай. Вызван он тем, что почти(?) все популярные реализации `std::string` используют т.н. SSO(small string optimization), при которой вся строка хранится в самом объекте, при её малом размере. Но если записать в строку больше, чем внутренний буфер позволяет, вся строка обязательно будет перемещена в кучу процесса.

После этого, достучаться до этой строки уже не получится так просто. И, попытавшись прочитать или записать что-либо в строку во втором процессе, Вы получите UB, т.к. адрес строки, содержащийся в `std::string` указывает на область памяти выделенной в первом процессе. В общем случае, во втором процессе этот адрес никем не будет занят, либо будет занят, но совсем другим объектом — в любой из этих ситуаций, обращение к этому адресу как к `std::string` будет UB(если не совпадёт, конечно, что там окажется другая строка, по точно такому же адресу и такого же размера, но подобные «чудеса» я в рассмотрение не беру.

---

Если же абстрагироваться от примера, то есть простое правило: если хочешь обменяться данными с любой внешней сущностью(будь то процесс или ещё что-то), сначала сохрани это в каком-то общем для обеих сущностей формате, чтобы принимающая сторона могла безошибочно определить, что ей пришло. Использовать простые объекты C++ языка в такой взаимодействии нельзя, т.к. слишком много мест, где можно «поскользнуться».

Comment: про сериализацию понял, спасибо, звучит вполне разумно. Но почему нельзя делать таким образом - до сих пор не ясно. И не ясно, почему в одном процессе поле std::string меняется, а в другом - нет. Также не понятно, в чем проблема с указателем на "внешнюю память"? Мне казалось, что абсолютно без разницы, где лежит указатель(в shared memory или нет) для того, чтобы с этим указателем работать. Буду рад дельным комментариям от вас по этим вопросам.

Comment: @Shadr, потому что если Вы выделяете общую память под 2 процесса, то только она доступна этим процессам. В общем случае, 2 процесса не могут читать память друг друга. `std::string`, который выделен в этой общей памяти имеет внутри себя указатель, который указывает на блок памяти, содержащий символы(т.е. саму строку). В общем случае, это блок памяти содержится в куче процесса и не имеет отношения к разделяемой памяти. Поэтому, чтобы другой процесс мог к нему добраться, ему нужно знать адрес и уметь читать память другого процесса. Адрес он знает, а читать не может(в общем случае).

Comment: если процесс не может читать, то должна возникнуть ошибка в  runtime? Просто в коде выше никаких ошибок не возникает, оба процесса успешно выводят на экран содержимое поля string name(я думаю, что это подходит под определение читать, поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь).

Comment: @Shadr, у Вас в коде потенциальное UB — падать программа вовсе не обязана, но может. Если выводит строку правильно, значит она влезает в буфер в рамках SSO(small string optimization). Введите символов 40 и тогда увидите, что правильно строка будет выведена только в том процессе, где ей было присвоено это значение.

Comment: вообще так и происходит, как вы говорите :) А UB тут в чем конкретно выражено?

Comment: @Shadr, В том, что Вы во втором процессе обращаетесь к памяти, которую не выделяли. Она выделена в первом процессе, а во втором  - нет.

Comment: спасибо за терпение :) есть предложение к вам - все эти комментарии собрать в один развернутый ответ.

Comment: @Shadr, обновил.