# Межпроцессное взаимодействие (Shared Memory)

Tags: c++, linux, c, memory, ipc

Kак я могу создать общий `class` для двух процессов в `Shared Memory`? Например я хочу чтобы этот `class` был обшим для двух процессов. Спасибо.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class HashTable
{
    struct Node
    {
        std::string login_;
        std::string password_;
        size_t  pos_file_;
        Node*   next_;
        Node(std::string login, std::string password, size_t pos_file = 0, Node* next = 0): 
                login_(login),
                password_(password),
                pos_file_(pos_file), 
                next_(next)
        {}
    };

    size_t hashCode(std::string login, std::string password) const;

public:
    HashTable(size_t size);
    ~HashTable(void);

    bool  search(std::string login, std::string password)const;

    void  insert(std::string login, std::string password);

    void  print()const;

private:
    Node** table_;
    size_t  size_; 
};

HashTable::HashTable(size_t size)
{
    size_ = size;
    table_ = new Node*[size];
    for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
        table_[i]=0;
}

HashTable::~HashTable(void)
{
    Node* temp;
    for(size_t i=0; i<size_; i++)
        while(table_[i]!=0)
        {
            temp=table_[i]; 
            table_[i]=temp->next_;
            delete temp;
        }
    delete []table_;
}

size_t HashTable::hashCode(std::string login, std::string password) const
{
    size_t sum = 5381;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < login.size(); ++i)
    {
        sum = sum * 33 + (size_t)login[i];
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < password.size(); ++i)
    {
        sum = sum * 33 + (size_t)password[i];
    }
    return sum % size_;
}

bool HashTable::search(std::string login, std::string password) const
{
    Node* vertex = table_[hashCode(login, password)];
    while (vertex)
    {
        if (vertex->login_ == login && vertex->password_ == password)
        {
            return true;
        }
        vertex = vertex->next_;
    }
    return false;
}

void HashTable::insert(std::string login, std::string password)
{
    Node* vertex = table_[hashCode(login, password)];
    Node* current = new Node(login, password, 0, vertex);
    table_[hashCode(login, password)] = current;
}

void  HashTable::print()const
{
    Node* current;
    for(size_t i=0; i<size_; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<i<<"::: ";
        for(current=table_[i]; current!=0; current=current->next_)
            std::cout<<current->login_<<" " << current->password_ << " " << current->pos_file_  << " ::: ";
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Именно процессов, а не потоков? вот есть либа для этого http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html

Comment: Что вы понимаете под - создать общий class?

Comment: когда один процесс меняет чего то в этом классе у другом процесе изминилься.

Comment: Вам уже писали в предыдущих вопросах, что для того, чтобы класс был размещен в *shared memory*, **все** выделения памяти в этом классе должны быть в области *shared memory*. У вас же используется `new`, который выделит память в области процесса.

Comment: Объяснение этого можете почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601467/char-%d0%b2-shared-memory-%d1%81). Все очень понятно рассказано.

Comment: А вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599998/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-pod-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-shared-memory-c) хорошо рассказано, почему нельзя выделять классы в области разделенной памяти. Вам нужна сериализация.

Comment: А использование именно отдельных процессов, а не потоков принципиально? Часто эти понятия путают. Так вот с потоками все гораздо проще. В чем суть задачи?